# Setting Locale in spring mvc Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am facing which having different scenario.I have portal which saves the locale of the user in database.When The use get logging.I am getting user detail but I don't know how to set it in controller.

I know that we can use `LocaleContextHolder` to set the locale but I dont know how it will work with controller. Please will you give some example

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showMotionProfile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showMotionProfile(Model model, RedirectAttributes attributes,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    logger.info("---------->country"+locale.getCountry());

    logger.info("\n--------------showMotionProfile-----------\n");
    LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(locale.ITALIAN);
    logger.info("---------->country"+LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());

    return "showMotionProfile";
}
```

Please tell me if I have done right,cause It is not reflecting.

Thanks for help.

EDIT: I have this resolver config in my spring xml file:

```
<beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleR‌​esolver"> 
    <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en" /> 
</beans:bean> 
<interceptors> 
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeI‌​nterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="locale"></beans:property> 
    </beans:bean> 
</interceptors>
```

Can I use this by using `@Autowired` in my controller and setting the locale?

Comment: Don't. Just implement a custom `LocaleResolver` and configure it appropriatly.

Comment: I have this resolver config in my spring xml file.
<beans:bean id="localeResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
  <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
 </beans:bean>
 <interceptors>
  <beans:bean
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
   <beans:property name="paramName" value="locale"></beans:property>
  </beans:bean>
 </interceptors>

Can I use this by doing autowired in  my controller and set the locale.

Comment: Please don't add config as comments, modify your post. I fyou configuration is stored in a database yuo need a custom `LocaleResolver` which initially reads it from DB, stores in in the session or cookie (or whatever) and has a nice fallback. Then you can use the regular `LocaleChangeInterceptor` to modify the `Locale`.

Comment: I have saved locale in session can I use LocaleChangeIntercepter by my self  in controller to change the locale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you are on the right track:

- Add the `SessionLocaleResolver` to your application context.
- Add the `LocalChangeInterceptor` to your application context, but note that **this will only change the current locale, if "locale" is passed as request parameter to any of your web controllers**.
- Alternatively, inject the sessionLocalResolver into your Controller (using `@Autowire` or the application context XML) and call the `setLocale` method on it. That way you can pass it the locale value from your database.