# Why Thymeleaf is showing a strange symbol when using numbers.formatCurrency(value)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I´m learning Spring MVC, and i´m using Thymeleaf to add logic to the views.
The video that i´m following, shows this line of code:

```
<div class="col-md-5"> Valor: <span th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(order.negotiatedValue)}">200,99</span></div>
```

In this video, he shows that the Symbol is R$ (because he is in Brazil). I´m in Brazil too, but I received this weird symbol: ¤

[image]

Why is this happening? Is there a way to force it to show the same Brazilian currency symbol, without hardcoding the string (adding R$ at the beginnning)?

Comment: That `¤` character is the [generic currency sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)), which in your case is probably being used because of the default locale your Spring app is using. For example, my app uses a locale of `en-US` and the symbol I see is `$`.

Comment: There are various ways to manage the locale you want to use. See [Setting Locale in spring mvc Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824839/setting-locale-in-spring-mvc-controller) for one approach. You can also use [the Thymeleaf `#locale` object](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#expression-basic-objects) to see what locale your Thymeleaf renderer is picking up.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was.
When using Google Chrome as a client, you should see the language of your browser, and see if it is a language of a specific country, or it is a language of a region.
In my case, i had the "Spanish(Latin America)" region selected, and that caused the unexpected currency sign.
[image]

The solution is to move to the top the language of a specific country, like "Spanish(Argentina)".
[image]

Thanks everyone for the other possible solutions.